# Django template system - getting fields from template

Tags: django, templates, field

Is there a function that returns a list of fields that are expected in template? For example, I have the following template:

```
hello i am {{ name }}. {% for i in docs %} i have doc {{ i }}
```

Written in file. And i want to get a dict which contains:

```
{'name': 'str', 'docs': 'list'}
```

Is there something like that or i have to write it by myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know, NO....

Your template contains some html and some **place holders** (and may be something else). What `render_to_template` doing is, it gets a context dictionary which contain some keys and some data attached to that keys and a template. Then it places the values to those place holders according to their key names, execute some loops or condition checks if your template contains control flows like `{% if...%}` or `{%for....%}`

If `TEMPLATE_DEBUG` is closed in your settings, and if there is a place holder with no matching key in your context dictionary, then it will skip that without raising any error.

Also, if you pass a form object to your template and place your object directly to template as it is (without calling each field separately) [ex: `{{form}}` or `{{form.as_p}}` then django will check for fields on the form and palce them [as it is shown here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/api/#as-p). In a such situation, you will only know that form is used. You have to check which fields are used from your `Form` definition.

If you look through that process, you **must** know what you need to place your context dictionary. You may write a parser to parse your template but it is far more difficult than just examining the template and find missing data, i guess.

Answer (score 0):

The builtin {% debug %} tag may be helpful for you, however I don't know if I fully understand what you are asking.  Basically, if you put the debug tag in your template it will print a lot of useful stuff, including all the variables available in your template.

Perhaps you could take a look at the source code for the [debug tag](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/defaulttags.py#L79) (because they have access to all the variables there), and build a [custom tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-template-tags/) tag based off of this.  Taking a glance at the source, this seems like it would be really simple to do.